# Windows upgradation in Azure

Tags: windows, azure, upgrade

Do we have an option to upgrade Windows OS in Azure?

I'm looking for a solution to upgrade my WINDOWS OS in Azure.  I didn't find any answer.

Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As per the following [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines#kb-link-2)

> Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a Microsoft Azure virtual machine"
>
> To work around this issue, create an Azure VM that's running a supported version of an operating system, and then migrate the workload ([Method 1,](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014997/an-in-place-system-upgrade-is-not-supported-on-windows-based-azure-vms) preferred), or download and upgrade the VHD of the VM ([Method 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4014997/an-in-place-system-upgrade-is-not-supported-on-windows-based-azure-vms#media-print)).